# R - Transferring values from certain columns in certain rows to matched IDs from propensity score matching

Tags: r, join, dplyr, match

I have two data frames: one containing the IDs of pairs of participants that were matched using propensity score matching (i.e., each row has the two matched IDs; `df1`) and one containing longitudinal data in **long format** for all participants (`df2`).

In each matched pair, one person is from the experimental group and the other is from the control group. Group is indicated by the variable `Group`. In df2, participants from the experimental group have values on the variables `Year` and `Month` whereas participants from the control group only have NA’s on these variables. I now aim to copy the values on `Year` and `Month` of the experimental group participant to their matching partner from the control group (based on the information about matched IDs from `df1`).

```
df1 <- read.table(text=
"ID_EG  ID_CG
800057  834341
800119  897177
800125  834011", header = TRUE)
```

```
df2 <- read.table(text=
"ID       Group    Year      Month
800057    1        2008      2         
800057    1        2008      2   
800057    1        2008      2   
800057    1        2008      2   
800057    1        2008      2   
800119    1        2014      10  
800119    1        2014      10         
800119    1        2014      10   
834011    0        NA        NA  
834011    0        NA        NA    
834341    0        NA        NA   
834341    0        NA        NA   
834341    0        NA        NA    
834341    0        NA        NA    
834341    0        NA        NA   
800125    1        2010     5
800125    1        2010     5
897177    0        NA       NA
897177    0        NA       NA
897177    0        NA       NA", header=TRUE)
```

Can anyone help me how to get this done for each matched pair? I tried looping but since I'm very new to R, I was swamped.

My expected outcome would look like this (`df3`):

```
df3 <- read.table(text=
"ID       Group    Year      Month
800057    1        2008      2         
800057    1        2008      2   
800057    1        2008      2   
800057    1        2008      2   
800057    1        2008      2   
800119    1        2014      10  
800119    1        2014      10         
800119    1        2014      10   
834011    0        2010      5  
834011    0        2010      5    
834341    0        2008      2   
834341    0        2008      2   
834341    0        2008      2    
834341    0        2008      2    
834341    0        2008      2   
800125    1        2010      5
800125    1        2010      5
897177    0        2014      10
897177    0        2014      10
897177    0        2014      10", header=TRUE)
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possible solution to achieve such task. Basically, we first create a `lookup` table where each ID with `Year` and `Month` is paired with its relative participant without `Year` and `Month`. Afterwards, we use a left join and `coalesce` the `NA` values of `Year` and `Month` in order to obtain a new column without missing values.

```
library(dplyr)

lookup <- df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by = c("ID_EG" = "ID")) %>% select(-Group) %>% distinct()
#    ID_EG  ID_CG Year Month
# 1 800057 834341 2008     2
# 2 800119 897177 2014    10
# 3 800125 834011 2010     5

df2 %>%
  left_join(lookup, by = c("ID" = "ID_CG")) %>% 
  mutate(
    Year = coalesce(Year.x, Year.y),
    Month = coalesce(Month.x, Month.y)
    ) %>% 
  select(!ends_with(".x") & !ends_with(".y"), -ID_EG)
```

Final output

```
       ID Group Year Month
1  800057     1 2008     2
2  800057     1 2008     2
3  800057     1 2008     2
4  800057     1 2008     2
5  800057     1 2008     2
6  800119     1 2014    10
7  800119     1 2014    10
8  800119     1 2014    10
9  834011     0 2010     5
10 834011     0 2010     5
11 834341     0 2008     2
12 834341     0 2008     2
13 834341     0 2008     2
14 834341     0 2008     2
15 834341     0 2008     2
16 800125     1 2010     5
17 800125     1 2010     5
18 897177     0 2014    10
19 897177     0 2014    10
20 897177     0 2014    10
```

Comment: `coalesce` is realy nice function for this problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% select(-Group), by = c("ID_EG" = "ID")) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  pivot_longer(contains("ID"), values_to = "ID", names_to = "Group") %>% 
  mutate(Group = ifelse(Group == "ID_EG", 1, 0)) %>% 
  left_join(df2, ., by = "ID") %>%
  select(-contains(".x")) %>%
  data.table::setnames(str_subset(names(.), ".y"), str_subset(names(.), ".y") %>% str_remove(".y"))
```

gives:

```
       ID Year Month Group
1  800057 2008     2     1
2  800057 2008     2     1
3  800057 2008     2     1
4  800057 2008     2     1
5  800057 2008     2     1
6  800119 2014    10     1
7  800119 2014    10     1
8  800119 2014    10     1
9  834011 2010     5     0
10 834011 2010     5     0
11 834341 2008     2     0
12 834341 2008     2     0
13 834341 2008     2     0
14 834341 2008     2     0
15 834341 2008     2     0
16 800125 2010     5     1
17 800125 2010     5     1
18 897177 2014    10     0
19 897177 2014    10     0
20 897177 2014    10     0
```